# R Regular Expressions: How do I get the full matched string

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I am trying to get the full RegEx match out from R, but I can only seem to get the first portion of the string.

Using http://regexpal.com/ I can confirm that my RegEx is good and that it matches what I expect. In my data, the "error type" is found between the number preceded by an asterisk and the next comma. So I'm looking to return `"*20508436572 access forbidden by rule"` in the first instance and `"*20508436572 some_error"` in the second.

Example:

```
library(stringr)

regex.errortype<-'\\*\\d+\\s[^,\\n]+'
test_string1<-'2014/08/07 08:28:56 [error] 21278#0: *20508436572 access forbidden by rule, client: 111.222.111.222'
test_string2<-'2014/08/07 08:28:56 [error] 21278#0: *20508436572 some_error, client: 111.222.111.222'

str_extract(test_string1, regex.errortype)
str_extract_all(test_string1, regex.errortype)
regmatches(test_string, regexpr(regex.errortype, test_string1))

str_extract(test_string2, regex.errortype)
str_extract_all(test_string2, regex.errortype)
regmatches(test_string2, regexpr(regex.errortype, test_string2))
```

Results:

```
> str_extract(test_string1, regex.errortype)
[1] "*20508436572 access forbidde"
> str_extract_all(test_string1, regex.errortype)
[[1]]
[1] "*20508436572 access forbidde"

> regmatches(test_string1, regexpr(regex.errortype, test_string1))
[1] "*20508436572 access forbidde"

> str_extract(test_string2, regex.errortype)
[1] "*20508436572 some_error"
> str_extract_all(test_string2, regex.errortype)
[[1]]
[1] "*20508436572 some_error"

> regmatches(test_string2, regexpr(regex.errortype, test_string2))
[1] "*20508436572 some_error"
```

As you can see, the longer match is truncated, but the shorter one is correctly parsed.

Am I missing something here, or is there some other method to get the full match back?

Cheers,

Andy.

Comment: Your regexp expression captures the n in forbidden and not a newline, which i suppose you thought.

Comment: Just looked at that by moving the "n" and this appears to be true. Do you know if that is a probalem with RegEx in R, as "\n" has nothing to do with "n"?

Comment: I normally use gsub for regexp, and there it makes no difference, but using the stringr packages it depends if there are a even or odd number of backslashes used. If I have similar problems I often use try-and-error to find the right solution ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 str_extract_all(test_string1, perl("(?<=\\#[0-9]\\: )\\*\\d+\\s[^,\\n]+"))[[1]]
#[1] "*20508436572 access forbidden by rule"

str_extract_all(test_string2, perl("(?<=\\#[0-9]\\: )\\*\\d+\\s[^,\\n]+"))[[1]]
#[1] "*20508436572 some_error"
```

Using Lookbehind

`(?<=\\#` Look for `#`

`[0-9]`  followed by a number

`\\:`   followed by `:` and a space

Then used your pattern

Comment: Great - worked a treat. What is the function of the "(?<=\\#[0-9]\\: )" string in this example?

Comment: I'm not sure why applying that lookbehind returned the full string - I need to apply this to other parts of my data where that lookbehind won't be valid.

Comment: @Andy Crellin. It is regex Look behind.  Check this link <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups>

Comment: @Andy Crellin.  Without the `\\n`, I am getting the expected output. `str_extract_all(test_string1, '\\*\\d+\\s[^,]+')`

Comment: akrun, @Jörg Mäder: Thanks for both your comments. Simply replacing \n with [:cntrl:] seems to have solved the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `gsub` method that removes your desired string in both cases, without re-writing the regular expression.

```
> gsub("((.*)[*])|([,](.*))", "", c(test_string1, test_string2))
# [1] "20508436572 access forbidden by rule" 
# [2] "20508436572 some_error"
```

In the regular expression `((.*)[*])|([,](.*))`,

- `((.*)[*])` removes everything up to the `*` character.
- `|` means "or"
- `([,](.*))` removes the comma, and everything after it.